# Whats the best way to convert a datarow[] to List<int>?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to convert a `datarow[]` into a `List<int>`

```
List<int> UserIds;

    public void GetGravatars()
    {
        var cmd = access.GetSqlCommandStoredProcedure("uspMembershipGetUserGravatarList");
        var table = access.ExecuteDataTable(cmd, DAL.Logic.Common.ConnectionStrings.User);

        int[] rows = new int[table.Rows.Count];
        table.Rows.CopyTo(rows, 0);
        UserIds = rows.ToList<int>();

    }

    public bool UserHasGravatar(int userId)
    {
        UserIds.Find(
            delegate(int i)
            {
                return i == userId;
            }
        );
        return false;
    }
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Edit: My code needs to loop through a list of users, about 40000, and update their image, if they dont have one, so I thought it would be quickest, to load all the userids with images into a List, then check that against all userids in the database, if userid doesnt exists, then update image, otherwise continue.

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you want a List of ints, or an array of hints? Question title and sample code seem to disagree as to what you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rows.Select(r=>/*However you get a single int from a single row*/).ToList();
```

**Update:**

I assumed that you are using .NET Framework 3.5? But I may be wrong...

Comment: He needs an int[]-Array. So it's ToArray() ;-)

Comment: Oh well, his UserIds type shows List<int>, looks like the specs are contradictin' :)
And yes, you can simply use the other extension method, ToArray()

Comment: Sorry, I meant I wanted a List<int>